# How to determine CallKit Call Directory App Extension limits?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, callkit

I have an iOS application and recently added Call Directory extension to my application in order to manage calls blocking & identification. I want to know the maximum amount of numbers that can be added to my Call Directory block list. I tried to do that test manually and added about 16.000.000 entries. I did that by adding them 100.000 chunks one by one and could add more. I also tried to find any documentations about this limits, but had no luck with that either.

Do you know how to determine it in a better way or should I just keep adding 100.000 chunks? Might be someone was facing this question in the past?

Comment: I don't believe that there is a limit (except perhaps the entire number space of Int64)

Answer (score 0):

Did a lot of experiments and found out the following:

Call Directory Extension's limits depend from the device memory, so as was mentioned in the comments there are no any specified limits.

Amount of uploading data per time to Call Directory Extension also depends from the device memory. When testing on iPhone 6S, I could upload up to 100.000 entries at once. With newer device it scales up.

That's everything I found out for so far, hope that will help someone.

Comment: How were you able to upload 100K at once without going over the 12 MB memory limit? The most I could do at once before hitting that limit was 30K, and I was using a simple `for` loop incrementing an integer.